# movable combobox in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I want to use external physical combobox which is filled with dataset. I want this combobox to be available in the grid at particular cell address when I enter into that cell. navigation should be with keyboard. thanks in advance

I use following code but it does not available in Cell enter & also keyboard navigation are not working.
1-Formload
`datagridview1.Controls.Add(conbobox1);`

2-Cell Begin Edit

```
private void datagridview1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, 
                                         DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (datagridview1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 16)
    {
        conbobox1.Visible = true;
        conbobox1.Size = datagridview1.CurrentCell.Size;
        conbobox1.Location = datagridview1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(
                                           e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `DataGridComboBoxCell` in a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. I wrote an example for you (all in code):

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cell.Items.Add("Sth1");
cell.Items.Add("Sth2");
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow(); 

if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count == 0)
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
row.Cells.Add(cell);
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

But you can add that Column in design-time.

Comment: you cant put the `System.Windows.Form.ComboBox` in `Datagridview`

Comment: i want DataGridViewComboBoxColumn work as a DropDown not  like DropDownlist.